# aws cli how to set compute type for code build project?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, aws-codebuild

aws cli how to set compute type for code build project?

AWS Console has limited options to pick from:

[image]

I want to use new arm CPUs:

[image]

How to set with aws CLI?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

So to make this happen, i need to set environment type to `ARM_CONTAINER`, computeType to `BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL`, and image to: `aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-aarch64-standard:2.0`

The aws CLI answer:

```
aws codebuild update-project --name user-api-production --environment '{"type": "ARM_CONTAINER", "computeType": "BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL", "image": "aws/codebuild/amazonlinux2-aarch64-standard:2.0"}'
```

**CLI docs:**

Take a note that `environment` is complex type, you need to pass in valid JSON with all the values. Also my CLI command's JSON above does not include `environmentVariables` and if you had any env. variables set before the command, those variables **will be removed**.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/codebuild/update-project.html

**Images:**

Here is link to all docker images provided by CodeBuild, it is possible to use custom image too.

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-available.html

Can get the list with CLI too:

`aws codebuild list-curated-environment-images`

**Environment Types & Compute Types:**

[image]

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/codebuild/latest/userguide/build-env-ref-compute-types.html

**Inside AWS Console:**

Also actually you can use AWS Console, to get access to arm CPUs, need to change the image and then new compute types are available:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

To use `arm1.small` in codebuild, you need to set the instance to `BUILD_GENERAL1_SMALL` (which is what you currently have selected in the console). In addition to this, you also need to set the environment type to `ARM_CONTAINER`. The environment type is what determines if it's x86 Linux, Windows, or ARM Linux.

Comment: was looking for CLI command sample, i know i need to change the instance type & env. yet i needed exact CLI command, which i managed to find out from documentation and with some try  & error get the working command and posted as answer on this same question

Answer (score 0):

> AWS Console has limited options to pick from

Actually, the console has all the necessary options in order to pick ARM based images.

In order to use the ARM type compute types, you have to select a custom build image in CodeBuild:

[image]

This will allow to select ARM build environments. You also can chose between the compute and memory options in the additional configurations:

[image]

Now, if you selected a build image which is not managed by AWS, you will have to create you own Docker container used for build environment. AWS provides step-by-step instructions on how to do that: [source](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/devops/extending-aws-codebuild-with-custom-build-environments/).